# JFreeChart Gantt Chart zooming issue

Tags: java, jfreechart, gantt-chart

I think there is a bug in JFreeChart's Gantt chart. When I'm zooming in finally I get something like this...

[image]

and if I zoom a little bit more ...

[image]

Is there any workaround for that behaviour?

Comment: Are sub-second intervals a realistic zoom level?

Comment: @trashgod I don't know, but anyway this example is taken from the official jfree demo application. And the zooming result is a bit confusing.

Comment: I don't know either. I see that the effect actually occurs at sub-millisecond intervals. Panning doesn't appear to restore the rendering.

Comment: I think it is a bug. something similar occured for if I remember well stepcharts, but already has been fixed in relase 16 or 17.

Comment: Could be, but renderer could also see such an interval as empty.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116777).

Comment: ? Yes I added it there, but didn't get any answer yet.